# Split series of paragraphs by paragraph based on strcount

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a unique situation... I need to take a 12,000+ character string and split it into 1,000 character segments.  The trick is, I need to avoid breaking paragraphs.  I'm wondering if preg_match_all might be the best solution.  Currently I'm using a simple [str_split](http://php.net/str_split)() by character count.  I need the split to be by paragraph tags `<p></p>`

Has anyone done this before?  Can you offer me any tips on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are paragraphs denoted consistently by two line returns (\n)? Or are we dealing with HTML paragraphs? (<p>)

Comment: Good question - html paragraphs

Comment: There's http://php.net/wordwrap, which'd probably help. But without knowing how you've marked paragraph breaks (`\n\n`? `<p>`? `<br><br>`?), it's probably a bit too heavy handed.

Comment: What do you do with excess characters if a paragraph has more than 1,000 characters?

Comment: It simply goes on the next set... split() returns an array of pieces split by 1,000 characters

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's `DOMDocument` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) , you can parse the HTML and then loop each paragraph, doing whatever truncation you'll need to do.

In my example code below, I assume that you'll want to remove any HTML tags from within the paragraph text before limiting the text to 1,000 characters - otherwise, the HTML tags would count as characters and you'd end up with less than 1,000 readable characters.

```
   // create a new DOMDocument
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    // load the string into the DOM (this is your 12,000 character string)
    $doc->loadHTML('<p>Paragraph text</p><p>Paragraph text</p><p>Paragraph text</p><p>Paragraph text</p>');

    $paragraph_fragments = array();
    //Loop through each <p> tag in the dom and do... things to it
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
        // get the node's text, remove excess space and any internal HTML tags
        $text = strip_tags(trim($paragraph->nodeValue));
        // get the first 1000 characters from the string
        array_push($paragraph_fragments, substr($text, 0, 1000));
    }
    print_r($paragraph_fragments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way (assuming paragraphs are delimited by new lines).

First break up into paragraphs and then concat together.

**NOTE - This example was written before HTML paragraphs were specified in the question**

```
$hugeText = "..."

$paragraphSep = "\n"

$paragraphs = explode($paragraphSep, $hugeText);

$chunks = array();

$curChunk = '';
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph)
{
  // if it's ok to go over
  $curChunk .= $paragraphSep . $paragraph;    
  if (strlen($curChunk) >= 1000)
  {
     $chunks []= $curChunk;
     $curChunk = '';
  }

  // if it's not ok to go over
  if (strlen($curChunk) + strlen($paragraphSep) + strlen($paragraph) >= 1000)
  {
     $chunks []= $curChunk;
     $curChunk = $paragraph;
  }
  else
  {
     $curChunk .= $paragraphSep . $paragraph;    
  }
}
```

**Edit: Since paragraphs are now HTML rather than text.**

Basic premise still works - break apart the paragraphs, merge them back together.
Best to break apart html paragraphs using a dom parser.

Comment: Using string functions to parse HTML is a bad plan, FYI

Comment: @Chris - Originally this question was not HTML, just a string.  See the edit at the bottom.